# Create scrollbar only when text length greater than text area

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is some simple code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

rootwin = Tk()

roomtext = Text(rootwin)
roomtext.pack(side = 'left', fill = "both", expand = True)

rtas = ttk.Scrollbar(roomtext, orient = "vertical", command = roomtext.yview)
rtas.pack(side = "right" , fill = "both")

roomtext.config(yscrollcommand = rtas.set)

rootwin.mainloop()
```

As such, a default `scrollbar` appears straight away.
How is it possible to make the `scrollbar` appear once text entered is greater than text area?

So when I run code, first, `scrollbar` must not show. Then when enough text is entered `scrollbar` shows (i.e. text in `roomtext` longer than `roomtext` area).

Comment: It is best to use tkinter with OOP. Personally ive never used tkinter like this . Look for the `root.geometry()`. you can pass the dimensions of the window as a string like `root.geometry("500x600")`. This will allow you to have a window big enough to fit your stuff.

Comment: true, i do this.
if its hide in first, its beautiful on first look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this code is what you are looking for (changed pack to grid as I'm more familiar with it... You should be able to revert that easily if you want):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

rootwin = Tk()

roomtext = Text(rootwin)
roomtext.grid(column=0, row=0)

def create_scrollbar():
    if roomtext.cget('height') < int(roomtext.index('end-1c').split('.')[0]):
        rtas = ttk.Scrollbar(rootwin, orient = "vertical", command = roomtext.yview)
        rtas.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=N+S)
        roomtext.config(yscrollcommand = rtas.set)
    else:
        rootwin.after(100, create_scrollbar)

create_scrollbar()
rootwin.mainloop()
```

It checks if it needs to create a scrollbar 10 times every second.
With some additional changes you can even make it remove the scrollbar when no longer needed (text too short):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

rootwin = Tk()

roomtext = Text(rootwin)
roomtext.grid(column=0, row=0)

rtas = ttk.Scrollbar(rootwin, orient = "vertical", command = roomtext.yview)

def show_scrollbar():
    if roomtext.cget('height') < int(roomtext.index('end-1c').split('.')[0]):
        rtas.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=N+S)
        roomtext.config(yscrollcommand = rtas.set)
        rootwin.after(100, hide_scrollbar)
    else:
        rootwin.after(100, show_scrollbar)

def hide_scrollbar():
    if roomtext.cget('height') >= int(roomtext.index('end-1c').split('.')[0]):
        rtas.grid_forget()
        roomtext.config(yscrollcommand = None)
        rootwin.after(100, show_scrollbar)
    else:
        rootwin.after(100, hide_scrollbar)

show_scrollbar()
rootwin.mainloop()
```